# Can I solo mine ethereum instead of pool?

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining

I am running a single rx 480 at 22mh/s, this rig is not geared towards mining and I’m doing it for fun. Would I be able to solo mine ethereum blocks for a higher payout? Or should I stick to pool mining from the difficulty being too high?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

Answer (score 1):

There are several variables which you need to know before working out if this is a viable approach. You know your hash rate is 22mh/s, and an 8GB rx 480 has a maximum draw of around 170 watts.

You will want to find out what your cost of KW/h is, and put these values into a calculator such as [this one.](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/eth)

On the basis that your KW/h is $0.15, you would be making around $14.60 per month, if the average time to mine a block is 15 seconds, and Eth stays at $645.